# Почему не останавливается слайдшоу

Tags: jquery, javascript

Я написал простенький скрипт для движения картинки одна за другой через определённый интервал, но с при клике на остановку слайдшоу ничего не происходит, картинки как и раньше передвигаются. Вот код:

```
lightbox.on('click.slide', '#slideHandler', function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('startSlide')) {
        $(this).attr('class', 'stopSlide');
        var slideshow = setTimeout(function sshow(){
            imgright($('.imgtarget'), $('.imgstart'), $('#numberPhoto'));
                setTimeout(sshow, 4000);
            }, 4000);
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('stopSlide')) {
        clearTimeout(slideshow);
        $(this).attr('class', 'startSlide');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: сделайте fiddle, на первый взгляд у вас ошибка в том, что вы делаете второй setTimeout без присвоения к slideshow, просто напишите

    function sshow(){
         imgright($('.imgtarget'), $('.imgstart'), $('#numberPhoto'));
         slideshow=setTimeout(sshow, 4000);
    }, 4000);

а var slideshow надо объявить выше `lightbox.on`

Comment: Такой вариант полностью устраивает: меняются кнопки, слайдшоу и запускается, и останавливается.

Answer (score 2):

Дополнительно к коменту, я бы вообще упростил код

```
//изначально, нет startedSlide
var slideshow;
lightbox.on('click.slide', '#slideHandler', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.toggleClass('startedSlide');
    clearTimeout(slideshow);
    slideshow=setTimeout(sshow, 4000);
    function sshow() {
        if (!$this.hasClass('startedSlide')) return;
        imgright($('.imgtarget'), $('.imgstart'), $('#numberPhoto'));
        slideshow=setTimeout(sshow, 4000);
    }
    //return false; //не обязательно, просто чтобы показать точку выхода
});
```

Comment: Почему-то этот вариант работает со второго щелчка по кнопке запуска слайдшоу после создания лайтбокса. А дальше кнопка работает как надо.

Comment: И ещё мой вариант с двумя классами удобен (и главное работает) для визуальной смены кнопок Play и Pause.

Comment: Ой нет, всё нормально, работает с первого щелчка. Просто я забыл удалить в скрипте изначально заданный класс.